# uninstall doc viewer in emacs

Tags: dired, docview

I am trying to open files in Emacs using dired.  But whenever I open pdf files, the doc viewer in Emacs keeps loading the document.  Is there any 
way to stop the pdf files being opened in Emacs buffer?

Comment: From the docstring: "You can use C-c C-c to toggle between displaying the document or editing it as text."

Comment: What do you want Emacs to do instead of passing the files to `doc-view-mode`?

Answer (score 1):

The major mode is selected [automatically](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Major-Mode.html#Auto-Major-Mode) according to a bunch of rules, including looking at variable `auto-mode-alist`.  Its initial value includes:

```
("\\.\\(?:PDF\\|DVI\\|OD[FGPST]\\|DOCX?\\|XLSX?\\|PPTX?\\|pdf\\|djvu\\|dvi\\|od[fgpst]\\|docx?\\|xlsx?\\|pptx?\\)\\'" . doc-view-mode-maybe)
```

which selects `doc-view-mode-maybe` for (among others) files whose name is ending in `.pdf` or `.PDF`.  You can add a specific rule *before* this one to change how pdf files are handled:

```el
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (cons
    '("\\.pdf" . fundamental-mode)
    auto-mode-alist))
```

Also note that you can simply use `C-c C-c` to toggle between `doc-view-mode` and editing the document as text (as mentionned in `doc-view-mode` docstring).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a proper answer to the question coming but in the meantime...

I'm assuming your question relates to wanting to open some external PDF viewer within a desktop environment, rather than trying to edit the raw text of a PDF file within Emacs.

Not quite as easy as pressing `ENTER`, but pressing `!` within dired prompts to run a shell command on the current file. You can then specify your PDF viewer (such as "evince") and that will be executed on the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem for dvi, ps files, as well as pdf. The problem for me was in mailcap.el. I commented out the following 9 lines from line 165:

```
;;     ("pdf"
;;      (viewer . pdf-view-mode)
;;      (type . "application/pdf")
;;      (test . (and (fboundp 'pdf-view-mode)
;;         (eq window-system 'x))))
;;     ("pdf"
;;      (viewer . doc-view-mode)
;;      (type . "application/pdf")
;;      (test . (eq window-system 'x)))
```

I actually kept the original mailcap.el  and copied it with my modifications to my-mailcap.el. Then I put the following in my ~/.emacs

```
(require 'my-mailcap)
(autoload 'mailcap-parse-mailcaps "mailcap" nil t)
(autoload 'mm-mailcap-command "mm-decode")
(defadvice dired-view-file (around use-mailcap-mime-data activate)
"Use an external viewer to view a file according to `mailcap-mime-data'."
(unless (let ((file (dired-get-file-for-visit)) extension type command)
  (and (not (file-directory-p file))
       (progn
     (mailcap-parse-mailcaps)
     (setq extension (file-name-extension file)))
       (setq type (mailcap-extension-to-mime extension))
       (setq command (mailcap-mime-info type))
       (setq command (mm-mailcap-command command file nil))
       (prog1 t (shell-command command)))) ad-do-it))
```

Next I changed ~/.mailcap to bring up the application of your choice. For me, I used

```
application/pdf; xpdf %s
application/postscript; gv %s
application/x-dvi; xdvi %s
```

In dired, I now hit 'v' when the point is on the file I want and the appropriate application (xpdf, gv, xdvi) launches. If you still want docview then just hit return.

I found the above works with emacs-25 and emacs-26. However, do not use it for emacs-24; its mailcap.el does not need any modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can find solutions to this in the elpa/melpa repositories.  There are packages like `dired-open` which let you customize which action to take on a filetype.  You can even use alternate actions, like `enter` – opening it in an external program, `f` – edit the file in Emacs, `v` – view the file in Emacs' doc-view mode.